# SoftLayer : why is the image template status INACTIVE?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When trying to instantiate a server from an image template, the Python SL API returned :

```
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public):
Image template (#X) currently has the INACTIVE status, which
does not allow it to be used for a provision.
```

The control panel does not show status of images, but the details from the shell confirms this. How does one change the status of an image template and how can I turn its status back to ACTIVE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status only can be changed by a Softlayer's employee, you have to submit a ticket to softlayer and ask them to change the status.

Regards